# Delta over variable relations

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation

In the text I'm reading, which discuss the heat transfer by convection in stars, it shows that the relation $\rho \propto \frac{P}{T}$ (equation of state for an ideal gas) implies $$\frac{\Delta\rho}{\rho} = \frac{\Delta P}{P} - \frac{\Delta T}{T}$$ I don't know how to get from one equation to the other.

The text also says $\delta\rho = \frac{d\rho}{\rho}$ where $\delta\rho$ is a small variation of density. This doesn't seem right to me since the units wouldn't be consistent.

Comment: Take the natural log of both sides, and then evaluate  the differential of both sides.

Comment: @ChetMiller thanks, could you check the question I added. I forgot to include it.

Comment: I don't know about that other equation.  It looks wrong.